# changing div css at a specific page location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which puts a button fixed to the top of the page which overlays the content/images as the page scrolls.

HTML

```
<div id="btn">button</div> 

... images ...

... content ...
```

css

```
#btn { 
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0; right: 0;
}
```

I want to put an 'anchor' or something when the button reaches that point the #btn css changes to color: #000;

so essentially

```
 <div id="btn">button</div> 

... images ...

anchor changing the css 

... content ...
```

EDIT: the amount of content and images is not controlled by me so I don't know the distance from the top or bottom

Comment: are you using any CSS framework??

Comment: If you know the position of the element you could check the position of your button using .scrollTop() . If the position returned from scrollTop equals position of id. Do foo

Comment: I have implemented bootstrap in places. The problem is the position from the bottom/top changes since I don't control how much content or how many images are used.

Comment: check affix in bootstrap, you need something similar to that, affix changes the position from absolute to fixed with affix-top and affix classes. You can create your own class with different colors.

Comment: Im a bit confused as to how that solves my problem, The button should stay where it is, but when it scrolls to a specific 'target' it changes its css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have a javascript based solution for you. 
I hope this will help

https://jsfiddle.net/n9ssbL8h/1/

```js
window.onscroll=function(){
 if(document.getElementById('btn').getBoundingClientRect().top>= document.getElementById('header').getBoundingClientRect().top){
  document.getElementById('btn').style.color = '#fff';
  }else{
  document.getElementById('btn').style.color = '#000';
  }
}
```

```css
#btn { 
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0; right: 0;
}
#header{
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
#content{
  height: 400px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
<a id="btn">Button </a>
<div id="header">
Header
</div>
<div id="content">
Content
</div>
<div id="images">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the idea, just gotta adjust it for my code thank you! does that window code go in the header? (before head tags and in script tags)

Comment: Yeah you can add it to any where, should go to you js file

Comment: I am using wordpress, can I just add it to a js file? without needing to change anything?